# for SDCAlertCortroller - how do I get the width of the view? (whither SDCAlertViewWidth)

Tags: ios, sdcalertview

I've been using SDCAlertView, and am very happy with it.

I recently updated to the latest version, which now has SDCAlertController.

In the old way, I need to add some extra views onscreen, but one of them was an extra UILabel. I would create it with a frame that had the width as "SDCAlertViewWidth" minus about 20 points. This was a UILabel that could have as many lines as needed (0 lines), and I would call "sizeToFit" to force it to resize itself.

"SDCAlertViewWidth" isn't available in SDCAlertController. What is the best way to do this, under the new way of doing things?

Answer (score 1):

SDCAlertController has a `visualStyle`, which defines most of the appearance of the alert. You can use its `width` property to get the width of the alert.